# Powershell query with -like and wildcard

Tags: powershell

I currently use this script, called with 
-name nameofuser to get the current owner of a computerobject. problem is that if i write USER NAME i get results containing both USER and NAME not just "USER NAME"'s objects.

```
 param(
      [string]$name  
      )

    $1 = Get-ADComputer -filter * -Properties * | Where-Object {$_.ManagedBy -like "*$name*"}
    $1 = $1.name

    IF ($1 -eq $Null)

    {
    Write-Host "Unable to find computer with manager named : " -NoNewline
    Write-Host "$name" -ForegroundColor Red
    }

    else
    {
    Write-Host "Computername is : " -ForegroundColor DarkGreen -NoNewline
    Write-Host "$1" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
```

Comment: Can you show an example usage of this script? I see performance issues here with your use of `-Filter *` and `-properties *` but I am left to guess why you are not getting the results you expect since we dont see how you are calling the script.

Comment: Sorry, script is called by \\uncpath\scriptname.ps1 -name USER NAME
i use * in case  want to add some more functions in the future. it's not a big AD so it's not that bad of a query.

Comment: I don't see quotes around the string there? `\\uncpath\scriptname.ps1 -name "USER NAME"`

Comment: I tried only dubbelquotes... seems that was my mistake, single quotes work as it handles the entire name as 1 value
\\uncpath\scriptname.ps1 -name 'USER NAME' works, also just USER NAME works without quotes for wildcard search.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using -like try using -match. You wouldn't need a wildcard then.